Install old work electrical box on ceiling with blown cellulose insulation
We’re working on replacing a light fixture in our kitchen that turned out to not have an electrical box. This isn’t up to current code, so I’m looking to install an old work electrical box in the ceiling where the electrical wires currently are, which I’ve done a couple times before. However, in this case it’s on a vaulted ceiling that has blown cellulose insulation behind the drywall. Does anyone have any tips for how to go about installing an old work electrical box without messing up the vapor barrier in a scenario like this?

have a picture for us ?

I mean, you could just chip away at the drywall until you hit the backside paper facing, then poke something blunt up to break the paper, and just enlarge the hole to the desired shape/size carefully.
